# How do I solve Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

Tags: nvidia, xrandr, switchable-graphics

```
xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x46 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 4 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x1f4 cap: 0x0 crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-G0
thejas@thejas:~$ xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink 0x1f4 0x46
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  34 (RRSetProviderOffloadSink)
  Value in failed request:  0x1f4
  Serial number of failed request:  16
  Current serial number in output stream:  17
```

Comment: Have you switched to the X11 session? Which Ubuntu Version are you using?

Comment: It's telling you that the parameter to `--setprovideroffloadsink 0x1f4` is outside the range of values that this version of software supports on your hardware. Read `man xrandr`.